# Cross/Wide Page Images. Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, tumblr, uploading

I'm a beginner coding with Ruby. I'm currently building my first web project with image uploading. I would like to display the images with infinite scroll, wide and across the whole page, like [unsplash](http://www.unsplash.com)

On Unsplash, the images are wide and big. If someone could explain how to mimic or edit photos to be uploaded like this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I edited your question and removed the "personal" and "feelings" part, since this way it fits better as a question here. The question is too broad yet, but I believe a good question can be done on this topic with the right wording. Please consider think on it again - a good title would be "how to add an infinite scroll image on a page?"